# Tkinter How to set a Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I started today with Tkinter and I run into some problems. 
My goal is to open a window which loads a csv-file and outputs the column names as buttons and the rows as labels for each value. 
Now I want to be able to scroll down the labels.

I looked into this subject and I understand now that I need to frame my Button and Labels before I am able to add a scrollbar. 
With the code below, I am not able to scroll and the scrollbar goes down to the end of the list(instead of the end of the window).

For now my output looks like this:[Output of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNHBo.png)

with following error message:

```
TclError: unknown option "-yscrollcomand"
```

My code:

```
def open():
    # add new Window
    root1 = Toplevel()
    root1.title("this_is_a_first_try.csv")
    root1.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
    root1.configure(bg= "white")
    root1.geometry("1000x500")

    # add Data Frame
    data = pd.read_csv("this_is_a_first_try.csv")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    #create canvas
    canvas_main = Canvas(root1, bg= "gray")
    canvas_main.grid(row= 2, column= 1, sticky= "news", columnspan= len(df.columns))

    for index,title in enumerate(df.columns): # generating Buttons for headers of column
        if index == 0:
            Button(canvas_main, text= "Index").grid(row= 2, column= 1, sticky= W+E) # generating header for index-column
        else:
            Button(canvas_main, text= title).grid(row= 2, column= index + 1, sticky= W+E)
    for index1, row in enumerate(df.values): # generating Label-Widgets for values
        for index2, value in enumerate(row):
            Label(canvas_main, text= value, anchor= W).grid(row= index1 + 3, column= index2 + 1, sticky= W+E)


    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root1, orient= "vertical", command= canvas_main.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row= 2, column= len(df.columns) + 1, sticky= "ns")
    canvas_main.configure(yscrollcomand= scrollbar.set)
```

I can't find any solution in the internet,
If anyone could give me a hint what to look for, I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to display rows as labels rather than using a text widget?

Comment: _"I can't find any solution in the internet"_ - here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432

Comment: You can also use a listbox, if you wish.

Comment: @BryanOakley Because I wanted to seperate the csv data for each column. So I could access it easier later. Or should I put the value in a text widget instead?

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the link. I ll look into that. Was looking the whole day, but no problem really matched or it was weakly explained on youtube.

Comment: @TheMaker I will try it with a listbox. Thanks for the advice

Comment: ***TclError: unknown option "-yscrollcomand"***: Typo, should read `yscrollcommand=...`

Comment: I fixed the command. Saw it right after. Now I have to set the scrollbar to the lenght of the window. Thx for the advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a listbox. Below is a simple example with a listbox:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

window.geometry("500x500")
s = Scrollbar(window)
s.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
l = Listbox(window, height = 500, width = 500)
l.pack()


for i in range(1000):
    l.insert(END, i)

l.config(yscrollcommand = s.set)
s.config(command = l.yview)
window.mainloop()
```

You can just get all the elements in .csv file, and then put those in the list. Then, just use a for loop to insert all of the elements into the listbox, and done!!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I can scroll now. The problem I still have is, that now every row contains one string with all information. Is it possible to do something like 
for index1, row in enumerate(df.values): # generating Label-Widgets for values
        for index2, value in enumerate(row):
            l.insert(END, Label(l, text= value).pack())
So I can access every value of the string later? 
I want somethin similiar like excel, and as soon as I insert labels or buttons the scrollbar gets disabled.
Or isn't that possible?

Comment: Could you format the code properly? I kinda understand you, but if I could see the code you provided, I think I could help you better. Thanks mate!

Comment: @mimimiSNIPE I am not familiar with csv files, so sorry! :(

Comment: Thanks anyways. I understand now the concept of the Listbox :)

Comment: @mimimiSNIPE No, you misunderstand me. I will do some research about csv files, and then get back to you. I understand your code.

Comment: The link of @BryanOakley worked. The solution is there. I still don't understand the code, but it worked. Thanks to you all. 
Do I need to close this ? And if yes, how ?
Sorry it is only the second time I posted something.

Comment: @mimimiSNIPE You don't need to close. Just upvote BryanOakley's answer, and accept and upvote my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @mimimiSNIPE ***Do I need to close this ? And if yes, how ?***: Correct is **NOT** to upvote this answer, as it don't answer your question and close your question as duplicate using BryanOakleys provided link. Read up on [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @stovfl It does partially answer his question, and he didn't know this before. I will mark the question as duplicate, so it will be closed.